# What prevents the inlining of sqrt when compiled without -ffast-math

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, x86, clang

I stumbled upon this problem here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47063724/5769463): When not compiled with `-ffast-math` the `sqrt`-function was not inlined and thus `libm` was needed at link time.

However, I don't understand what is preventing the compilers (clang as well as gcc) from inlining the `sqrt`-function without the `-ffast-math`.

Compiling

```
#include <cmath>
double my_sqrt(double val){
  return sqrt(val);
}
```

with clang and `-02`  [yields](https://godbolt.org/g/zcoaYF) (similar with [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/B4nBqa), even if gcc's result doesn't look optimal to me):

```
my_sqrt(double):                            # @my_sqrt(double)
        sqrtsd  %xmm0, %xmm1
        ucomisd %xmm1, %xmm1
        jp      .LBB0_2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        retq
.LBB0_2:
        jmp     sqrt                    # TAILCALL
```

As I understand it, a build-in `sqrt`-function/CPU-instruction ([`sqrtsd`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_300.html)) is called and if result is `NaN` (PF-flag is set for [`ucomisd`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_316.html)) the library-version is used.

Maybe I'm mistaken, but `NaN` is the result if argument is negative, so what could the library-`sqrt`-function do better as to return a `NaN`? Why to call it then?

Comment: `sqrt()` has to set `errno` on NaN.  Use `-fno-math-errno` to omit conforming with this bad design decision that hardly any code ever wants.

Comment: @MichaelPetch In the linked question the answer must be somewhere along `It's using the library sqrt function for error handling.` but that seems to be a little bit curtly

Comment: I just finished expanding Jester's answer there to explain it better.  It's only to preserve the clunky `errno`-setting behaviour of the `sqrt()` library function that nobody cares about.  So use `-fno-math-errno`.

Comment: 'As I understand it, a build-in sqrt-function (sqrtsd) is called' - it does not call function, sqrtsd is CPU instruction.